# Setting up launch.json for Debugging Shopify CLI 3.5 Node App in VS Code

Tags: shopify-app, shopify-cli

I am developing an app using **Shopify CLI 3.5.0** and I am encountering challenges setting up a launch.json debug file in VS Code.

I aim to create a .vscode/launch.json that will let me debug server-side operations and also attach the debugger to the browser.

Here's how you can replicate my current setup:

```bash
npm init @shopify/app@3.5.0 -- --template=node
```

There are some additional steps you need to fill out and connect to your partner account.

When I do this in VS Code, I can see the .vscode folder, but the launch.json file is missing.

My main questions are:

1. Is there a recommended best practice for setting up and using the node debugger in VS Code for this scenario?
2. Could anyone provide a template or example of a launch.json file that works for debugging a Shopify CLI 3.5 app in VS Code?

Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance!